# how to set unique name and id of HTML Table columns which are dynamically created using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am creating one JSP page in which there is a textfield and button. If user enters some integer value lets say 2 in textfield, then 2 rows will be appended in Html table at last. So the rows of HTML table are being created dynamically.

I am implementing this using ajax call to a page which has `<tr>` data which is to be added to the main table after last row.

Everything is working fine. Rows are created dynamically using ajax call. But the problem is that all rows added to table have same column name attributes.

Below is my code:

main JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
.table {
    font-size: 11px;
}

#dailyTableDiv {
    height: 70%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
<script>
function addTask(){
    var n=$("#dailytsks").val();
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        $.ajax({url:"employeeSection/dailyTableRow.jsp",success:function(result){
            $('#dailyTable tr:last').after(result);
          }});  
    }


    //------------------------------
    // i am trying this code to set different names for different select box column.
    //but this is not happenting.
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        $("#chSelect").attr("name","chSelect"+i);
    } 
    //------------------------------
}

function add1Row(){
    $.ajax({url:"employeeSection/dailyTableRow.jsp",success:function(result){
        $('#dailyTable tr:last').after(result);
      }});  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="well">
            <input type="text" id="dailytsks" name="dailytsks" /><input
                type="button" name="addTsks" value="add" onclick="addTask();" /> <span
                style="margin-left: 20px;"></span><input type="button" value="+"
                id="add1" name="add1" onclick="add1Row();" /> <span
                style="margin-left: 20px;"></span><input type="button" value="-"
                id="minus" name="minus" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="dailyTableDiv">
            <table id="dailyTable" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Client Name</th>
                        <th>Task-Type</th>
                        <th>NBPE-Type</th>
                        <th>Task-Name</th>
                        <th>Planned-Hrs</th>
                        <th>Priority</th>
                        <th>Cross-Team</th>
                        <th>Current-Status</th>
                        <th>Is-Completed</th>
                        <th>Actual-Hrs</th>
                        <th>SMC-ID</th>
                        <th>SMC-URL</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

dailyTableRow.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<tr>
    <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- currently I am trying to set unique name for Select column only so i hv given it a ID -->
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chSelect" name="chSelect" /></td>
    <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <td width="3"><input type="text" style="max-width: 80px;"
        name="tskDate" /></td>
    <td><select name="cliName">
            <option>select client</option>
            <option>RWS</option>
            <option>Orgbase</option>
            <option>RW-MAAS</option>
            <option>WSO2</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chTskType" />NBPE?</td>
    <td><select name="tskNBPEType">
            <option>select NBPE type</option>
            <option>meeting</option>
            <option>on leave</option>
            <option>mom</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tskName" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" style="max-width: 15px;" name="plndHrs" /></td>
    <td><select name="tskPriority">
            <option>select priority</option>
            <option>low</option>
            <option>med</option>
            <option>high</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" style="max-width: 80px;"
        name="crosTeamMate" /></td>
    <td><select name="curStatus">
            <option>select status</option>
            <option>on hold</option>
            <option>in progress</option>
            <option>completed</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="isCompleted" value="N">No <br>
    <input type="radio" name="isCompleted" value="Y">Yes</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="max-width: 15px;" name="actHrs" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" style="max-width: 80px;" name="smcID" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" style="max-width: 160px;" name="smcURL" /></td>
    <td><textarea name="comment" rows="3" cols="10"></textarea></td>

</tr>
```

here all columns have same name which is wrong.
how can I make unique name attribute pairs for the column in rows which are added. Currently, as seen in the code I am only trying to set unique name attribute values to Select column only. But I am not able to do.

I want something like:

if name of column is "chSelect" then for two rows, it should become as :

chSelect1   &   chSelect2, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you

HTML:-

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="chSelect" class="chSelect" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chSelect" class="chSelect" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chSelect"  class="chSelect" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:-

```
var i = 0;
$('.chSelect').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('name', "chSelect"+i);
    i++;
});
```

LINK :-
https://jsfiddle.net/ft0uefaL/

Comment: where should i add the above mentioned javascript code in my case. When I added your code in my addTask() method just before it ends, it fails to change the name attribute values. I checked that in inspect element option in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to store the row number in a global variable that you'll increase each time you add a row via Ajax.

When your Ajax calls resolve, you parse the resulting html (`result`) using JQuery, change the `name` property of the `chSelect` element, and append the change to the last `tr` as you did previously:

```
// add a global variable to store row number
var row = 0;

function addTask(){
    var n = $("#dailytsks").val();
    var max = parseInt(n);

    for(i=1; i<=max; i++){
        $.ajax({
            url: "employeeSection/dailyTableRow.jsp",
            success: function(result){
                row += 1
                var newName = "chSelect" + row;

                var html = $('<div>').append(result);
                $(html).find("#chSelect").attr("name", newName)

                $('#dailyTable tr:last')
                  .after( html.html() )
            }
        });  
    }
}


function add1Row(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "employeeSection/dailyTableRow.jsp",
        success: function(result){
            row += 1;
            var newName = "chSelect" + row;
            var html = $('<div>').append(result);
            $(html).find("#chSelect").attr("name", newName)
            $('#dailyTable tr:last')
               .after( html.html() )
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: It is just showing 3 checkboxes now. No other components visible.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't modifying the resulting html properly, please try the edited version

Comment: This solution is not very elegant, you should consider passing a variable directly into the Ajax request, and use this variable to set-up the `name` property on the server side. You could also use a framework like Knockout.js [http://knockoutjs.com/] to do this in just a few lines of code

Comment: Oh, yes, you are so right. I should have passed a parameter like 1,2,3,4,... that the user has entered into ajax request URL. And then, on that particular page, I should have iterate my <tr> code by appending row number each time. Thanks for suggestion.